# Will my data from the infinite warefare beta be saved for when the game releases?

Tags: infinitewarfarebeta

I have access to the Infinite Warfare beta when it starts but I want to know if my leveling and unlocks will be saved for when the game releases? Does anyone know this yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to an [article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/erikkain/2016/10/14/the-call-of-duty-infinite-warfare-beta-starts-today-heres-what-you-need-to-know/#39367e732744) on Forbes regarding the release of the beta, **no, progress will not be kept after the beta ends.**

> "Don’t expect progress from the beta to carry over into the main game, which releases November 4th. You’ll have to start all over in terms of ranking up and progression."

Comment: As far as I remember, this has been the case for previous CoD betas as well.